# Parallel Worlds (really just with lines and planes)

Tags: geometry

Can someone help me understand/visualize why the two true/false questions below are false? I thought they were true.

True or False
2. Two lines perpendicular to a third line are parallel. CORRECT ANSWER: false

I'll respond quickly!

EDIT: Deleted one because I figured it out after typing it in!

Comment: "Two lines perpendicular to a third line are parallel." - in the plane, true; in space, false. See for instance [this related question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/27778).

Comment: Omg, duh moment! Thank you!

Comment: If you have *Mathematica*: `Graphics3D[{Line[{{0, 2, 1}, {0, -2, 1}}], Line[{{2, 0, -1}, {-2, 0, -1}}], Line[{{0, 0, 2}, {0, 0, -2}}]}, Boxed -> False]`

Comment: well, that had be true only in context of euclidean geometry @ silver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clarify here is a picture in 3-D[image]

Comment: Nice diagram!!!

Answer (score 2):

As others have answered in the comments, this is only true in the plane, not in 3D space.