# How can I find the points at which two 2D lines are a specific distance apart?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

I have two infinite lines in 2-dimensional space that are each defined by two $(x, y)$ points that they run through. The equations of the lines are:

$$\mathbf{P_a} = \mathbf{P1} + u_a(\mathbf{P2} - \mathbf{P1})$$
$$\mathbf{P_b} = \mathbf{P3} + u_b(\mathbf{P4} - \mathbf{P3})$$

Assuming these lines are not parallel, then for any given positive distance $D$, there will be exactly two points on each line where the closest point on the other line is exactly $D$ distance away, as seen on the below diagram. (For clarity/simplicity, only the points on the $\mathbf{P1} \to \mathbf{P2}$ line are shown, but they of course exist on the other line as well.) (If the lines are parallel, then there will be either zero or infinity such points. If $D$ is zero, then there will only be one point; i.e. the actual intersection point.)

[image]

So my question is, given these two lines and a desired distance $D$, how do I calculate the two $u_a$ values corresponding to the points on the $\mathbf{P1} \to \mathbf{P2}$ line at which the closest point on the other line is exactly $D$ distance apart? (I am specifically interested in the $u_a$ values; I do not need the actual $(x, y)$ points for my purposes, and if I did they would be trivial to calculate by substituting $u_a$ into the above equation. Obviously I can calculate the $u_a$ value from an $(x, y)$ point, but since this will ultimately be used in performance-critical computer code, I would prefer to not have to do that calculation if I can avoid it.)

Here's what you can assume:

- The lines are not parallel or coinciding. (Though if the solution can "let me know" when the lines are parallel, that would be ideal.)
- That $\mathbf{P1} \neq \mathbf{P2}$ and $\mathbf{P3} \neq \mathbf{P4}$
- That $D > 0$. (Though I'm guessing most solutions will also work for $D = 0$ and the two output $u_a$ values will simply be equal.)

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/27559/finding-points-on-two-linear-lines-which-are-a-particular-distance-apart) is the closest I've found to mine, but there are a couple of key differences:

- That question is about lines in 3D space, and my question is about lines in 2D space. (Which I assume makes the answer significantly simpler.)
- My lines are specifically defined by pairs of points that they run through.

Comment: It looks like you are *projecting* points of the orange line onto points of the gold line (via a third line perpendicular to the gold line), and want to find when the length of the projection (line segment joining orange to gold point) has length D. Is that right? If so then switching the two lines in this procedure will produce different points.

Comment: @coffeemath Yes that's correct.

Comment: Tweaked wording a bit to clarify.

Answer (score 2):

Let the two lines be $\mathbf{P_1}(t) $ and $\mathbf{P_2}(t) $ then we can write

$\mathbf{P_1}(t) = \mathbf{Q_1} + t \mathbf{V_1} $

$\mathbf{P_2} (t) = \mathbf{Q_2} + t \mathbf{V_2} $

It can be assumed that the direction vectors $\mathbf{V_1} $ and $\mathbf{V_2}$ are unit vectors.  To obtain the algebraic equations, Let unit vector $\mathbf{U_1} $ be orthogonal to $\mathbf{V_1}$ and unit vector $\mathbf{U_2}$ be orthogonal to $\mathbf{V_2} $, then

$ \mathbf{U_1} \cdot ( (x, y) - \mathbf{Q_1} ) = 0 $

$ \mathbf{U_2} \cdot ( (x, y) - \mathbf{Q_2} ) = 0 $

are the algebraic equations of the two lines.  To find which points on the first line are $d$ units from the second line, use the distance formula, and keep in mind that $\mathbf{U_1}, \mathbf{U_2}$ are unit vectors.  So now we have,

$ d = | \mathbf{U_2} \cdot (\mathbf{Q_1} - \mathbf{Q_2} + t \mathbf{V_1} ) |$

and this equation is of the form

$ d = | a + b t | $

its $t$ solutions are $t_1 = \dfrac{d - a}{b} $ and $t_2 = \dfrac{ - a - d }{b} $

Plugging these values in the parametric equation of the first line gives the required points.

The same procedure can be repeated for points on the second line that are $d$ units away from the first line, resulting in two solutions as well.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you want to find the points on line $\mathbf{P_a}$. You can write two scalar equations for $u_a$ and $u_b$:
$$
\cases{
(\mathbf{P_a}-\mathbf{P_b})\cdot(\mathbf{P_4}-\mathbf{P_3})=0\\
(\mathbf{P_a}-\mathbf{P_b})\cdot(\mathbf{P_a}-\mathbf{P_b})=D^2
}
$$
Solve the first equation (which is linear) for $u_b$ and substitute into the second equation, to find a resolvent quadratic equation in $u_a$.

Answer (score 1):

Recall : any line with equation

$$ux+vy+w=0$$ can be written (by dividing by $\sqrt{u^2+v^2}$) under the form (sometimes called the Euler form of the equation)

$$ x \cos \alpha + y \sin \alpha - p = 0$$

with a unique value for $\alpha$ (polar angle of the normal vector) and $p$ which has the interesting meaning of signed (shortest) distance from the origin to the line.

Therefore, there is a simple solution of your problem in 3 steps.

- obtain the equation of line $P_3P_4$ under its Euler form.
- consider lines which are offset lines of line $P_3P_4$ (parallel to it) at the desired distance $D$, i.e., with equations :

$$\begin{cases}(L_1): \ \ & x \cos \alpha &+& y \sin \alpha &-& (p+D) &=& 0 \\ (L_2):\ \ & x \cos \alpha &+& y \sin \alpha &-& (p-D)& =& 0\end{cases}$$

- compute the intersections of $(L_1)$ and $(L_2)$ with the second line $P_1P_2$.

Comment: Any comment ? ...